# Python A* pathfinding, what is this line doing?

Tags: python, a-star

I am reviewing this stack overflow post
[Python - Speed up an A Star Pathfinding Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159331/python-speed-up-an-a-star-pathfinding-algorithm)

I am trying to determine what the line `for tile in graph[current]:` represents. Namely what `graph[]` represents. I feel like graph should represent the entire grid, but I second guess this because we are giving current as argument to the [] operator on graph, so it has to be returning something, but im not sure what it should be. Maybe the tiles that we can travel to that are directly adjacent to current?

Also what does this syntax mean `current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]`?

```
import heapq

def aStar(self, graph, current, end):
  openSet = set()
  openHeap = []
  closedSet = set()

  def retracePath(c):
    path = [c]
    while c.parent is not None:
        c = c.parent
        path.append(c)
    path.reverse()
    return path

  openSet.add(current)
  openHeap.append((0,current))
  while openSet:
      current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
      if current == end:
          return retracePath(current)
      openSet.remove(current)
      closedSet.add(current)
      for tile in graph[current]:
         if tile not in closedSet:
             tile.H = (abs(end.x-tile.x)+abs(end.y-tile.y))*10 
             if tile not in openSet:
                 openSet.add(tile)
                 heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.H,tile))
             tile.parent = current
  return []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `graph` variable is a dict of some sort where the key is the current tile, and the value is a list of all the valid neighboring tiles. That way, every node in the graph is easily accessible via simple dict lookup.

The [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) on Wikipedia the author linked to in the original post supports this hypothesis -- the functionally equivalent line is listed as `for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)`

---

What the line `current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]` is doing is returning the literal tile object. If you observe the lines `openHeap.append((0,current))` and `heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.H,tile))`, you can observe that the author is adding a tuple of two elements to `openHeap` where the first element is the heuristic, and the second element is the literal tile object.

Therefore, the line `current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]` is identical to writing:

```
temp = heapq.heappop(openHeap)
current = temp[1]
```

...or to writting:

```
h, current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)
```

What the `heaqpq.heappop()` function itself is doing is returning the smallest element in the heap. Presumably, it's using the first element in the tuple to index, and so will return the open tile with the smallest heuristic as a cheap O(1) operation.